# Get the exit status of the last command in a pipeline

Tags: bash, pipe, echo

I'm trying to assign the exit command of the last command in a pipeline to a variable but it is not giving the expected result. Essentially I'm grepping a variable to see if it ends with '-SNAPSHOT' or not. So if I try this:

```
export PROJECT_VERSION=1.0.0
echo ${PROJECT_VERSION} | grep \\-SNAPSHOT$
```

And then do `echo $?` the result is `1` as expected (no match found).

If I then add the `echo $?` to the end of the pipe:

```
echo ${PROJECT_VERSION} | grep \\-SNAPSHOT$ | echo $?
```

The result then becomes 0.

How can I get the exit result of the `grep \\-SNAPSHOT` so that I can assign it to a variable?

Comment: `[[ $PROJECT_VERSION =~ -SNAPSHOT$ ]] && echo bingo`

Comment: Array PIPESTATUS contains return codes of all pipe members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit status is in `$?`.

```
echo ${PROJECT_VERSION} | grep \\-SNAPSHOT$
variable="$?"
```

Comment: Obvious now you put it. But can't work out why adding the `echo $?` to the end of the pipe affects the result.

Comment: @Kerry Making `echo $?` part of the pipeline gives you the result of the *previous* command/pipeline. All parts of a pipeline run simultaneously, so the `grep` hasn't finished yet.